# T-Post + Wire Trellis

Tags: fence, trellis

I am contemplating using 10' T-Posts (driven in 2' for 8' of height) with a wire (7/7 or other) across the top which I'll use to hang hooks to trellis tomatoes, cucumbers, butternut squashes and the like.  I have a 50' length and was going to put in posts every 6-8 feet.

My question is whether the wire - or posts - will buckle if I attach it to the t-posts using t-post clips or if I need to anchor them directly into the ground on either end to help resist the pull on the posts and wire.

Answer (score 2):

The posts will almost certainly pull towards each other (rather than "buckle") if you "pull on the posts" with the wire. This can be remedied by "guy-wiring" the posts, to give added resistance to directional pull.

Better yet, don't try to stretch the trellis wire tight.